# Compilation errors calling find_if using a functor

Tags: c++, stl

We are having a bit of trouble using find_if to search a vector of pairs for an entry in which the first element of the pair matches a particular value.  To make this work, we have defined a trivial functor whose operator() takes a pair as input and compares the first entry against a string.

Unfortunately, when we actually add a call to find_if using an instance of our functor constructed using a temporary string value, the compiler produces a raft of error messages.  Oddly (to me, anyway), if we replace the temporary with a string that we've created on the stack, things seem to work.

Here's what the code (including both versions) looks like:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> MyPair;
typedef std::vector<MyPair> MyVector;

struct MyFunctor: std::unary_function <const MyPair&, bool>
{
  explicit MyFunctor(const std::string& val)
    : m_val(val) {}

  bool operator() (const MyPair& p)
  {
    return p.first == m_val;
  }

  const std::string m_val;
};

bool f(const char* s)
{
  MyFunctor f(std::string(s));  // ERROR
  // std::string str(s);                                                                                                  
  // MyFunctor f(str);              // OK                                                                                                    
  MyVector vec;
  MyVector::const_iterator i = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), f);
  return i != vec.end();
}
```

And here's what the most interesting error message looks like:

> /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:260: error: conversion from ‘std::pair, std::allocator >, std::basic_string, std::allocator > >’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ requested

Because we have a workaround, we're mostly curious as to why the first form causes problems. I'm sure we're missing something, but we haven't been able to figure out what it is.

Comment: functor? that made me chuckle :)

Comment: @VoodooChild, why? The term functor is correct in this context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [most vexing parse](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=439).

You can do:

```
MyFunctor f(s);
```

or

```
MyFunctor f((std::string(s)));
```

The original declares a function `f`.  `f` takes a single argument, a pointer to a function taking an argument `s` and returning `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks! That clarified the situation perfectly.

Comment: ... or simply: `MyFunctor f( s )`. There is an implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string`, so there is no need to force that conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyFunctor f = MyFunctor(s);
```

is more clear and works the same.

Comment: ... or `MyFunctor f(s)`, which is even simpler and clearer (at least to me)

Answer (score -1):

The first error at

```
MyFunctor f(std::string(s));
```

is because std::string(s) is a rvalue(temporary) and the function

```
explicit MyFunctor(const std::string& val)
```

requires a reference that cannot be taken from rvalue.

The second error message you got is because you iterating over `vector<pair<string, string>>` which requires a functor that takes input of type `pair<string, string>` but your functor accepts input of type `string` which leads to the compilation error.

Comment: The `MyFunctor` constructor takes a `const` reference to a string.  Because of the `const`, a temporary is fine.  Once the functor is constructed, `find_if` only cares what parameters operator() takes.    That takes a const reference to a `MyPair`, as it should.